# Javascript ES6 Spread an array of undefined ...[,,]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So after running this code

```
'use strict';
var myNewArray = Array(...[,,]);
console.log(myNewArray);
```

I get this

```
[undefined, undefined]
```

Can anyone explain me why I get only 2 undefined?

Comment: Trailing commas are allowed to not add an element, which is a good thing. The bad thing is that the other  empty commas are permitted. Bizarre design decision, IMO, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 6):

You have provided `undefined` values in the array `[,,]`.

The last item is not calculated because JavaScript considers it as a trailing comma. So if `undefined` is provided, it will be thrown away from the array.

```
     [ , , ]
   //     ^^ -> Here is nothing, so array currently has 2 items with `undefined`
```

If you will give a value after it, it will be added in the result array.

```js
const myNewArray = Array(...[,,1]);
console.log(myNewArray);
```

Comment: i provided 3 undefined but i get only 2

Comment: I have explained it

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Suren's answer, you can clearly see in the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-literals-runtime-semantics-evaluation) that trailing elided elements are not counted into the length of the array.

> Elided array elements are not defined. If an element is elided at the end of an array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.